# How to make a Camera for canvas, as mine is not working JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, camera

I am trying to write a video game engine, however my camera doesn't update the movement of objects properly. I am trying to make it so that I update the position of something when the camera moves, and so the world would move around the camera, because you can't really make a camera that moves and update the coordinates that are drawn on the canvas, which would make this a lot easier. What happens is that the object will stutter across the screen instead of fluently move, which makes whatever game I make unplayable. here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epqx42m4/), lines of interest are 634, where an object moves, and 205 my camera class. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to do this

*P.S* I have seen this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/QKgHs/) and the Syntax gives me a headache, his if's don't use brackets and his classes are not conventional to me, so I cannot read it.

Some of my  camera code

```
    function cameras() {
  var cameraList = new Array();

  function camera(name, localPosX, localPosY, trackedEntity, edgeScrollingRadius) {
    var cameraID;
    var cameraName = name;
    var lPosX = localPosX;
    var lPosY = localPosY;
    var tEnt = trackedEntity || null;
    var scrollHowFar = edgeScrollingRadius || 0;

function moveCamera() {
  var movement = gameControls.getMovement();
  if (movement == "Left") {
    globalMove("Left");
  }
  if (movement == "Right") {
    globalMove("Right");
  }
  if (movement == "Up") {
    globalMove("Up");
  }
  if (movement == "Down") {
    globalMove("Down");
  }

}
this.cameraUpdate = function() {
  moveCamera();
}
}

  function createNewCamera(name, posX, posY, trackedEntity, edgeScrollingRadius) {
    console.log("created camera");
    var cam = new camera(name, posX, posY, trackedEntity, edgeScrollingRadius);
    if (cameraList.length == 0) {
      cam.cameraID = 0;
    } else {
      cam.cameraID = cameraList.length + 1;
    }
    cameraList.push(cam);
    console.log(cameraList);
  }

  function removeCamera(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= cameraList.length; i++) {
      if (cameraList[i].cameraID == id) {
        delete cameraList[i];
        cameraList.splice(i);
      }
    }
  }
```